# Selenium locating element - Angular

Tags: css, angularjs, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have to identity an element in the following HTML:

```
<main-nav-bar _nghost-oyw-6="">
<div class="navigation-bar" _ngcontent-oyw-6="">
<button _ngcontent-oyw-6="">Entities</button>
<button _ngcontent-oyw-6="">Entity settings</button>
<button _ngcontent-oyw-6="">Batches</button>
<button _ngcontent-oyw-6="">Documents</button>
</div>
</main-nav-bar>
</div>
```

The element I'm interested in is the one containing 'Entity settings'. I think the best way would be css or xpath but so far I haven't been able to identity one that works. My test keeps on failing. Any ideas?

Comment: Share your locators

Comment: For example: css = "div.header-bar > main-nav-bar > div.navigation-bar:nth-child(2)"

Comment: `css = "div.header-bar > main-nav-bar > div.navigation-bar:nth-child(2)"` means that you want to match second `div`, but not `button`. You can try `css = "div.header-bar > main-nav-bar > div.navigation-bar > button:nth-child(2)"` or simple `xpath = "//button[text()='Entity settings']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the element by name of the element you can try following solution :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Entity settings')]"));
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`//div[@class='navigation-bar']/button[2]`